# Android Studio freezes when changing a source file

Tags: android, android-studio, freeze

I really need some help with this.

I had to migrate from Eclipse to Android Studio. 
I exported my project (at first time - using "export" tool, at the second time manually - same result) and everything worked great (I worked for 2 days successfully) before I tried to make an apk-file. While making an apk-file, AStudio was complaining about some things like "change your customNS to res-auto" and when I did so, it started to freeze. If it freezes it's over, I have to kill the process of AS. When I reload AS, it makes a rebuild and then deadly freezes again. I figured, the build itself doesn't hang the AS, it freezes when I try to interact with source files. Try to print just a single letter - and it's over.

I ran this project on my friend's laptop (it's more powerful than mine) and it doesn't freeze there. But I'm not sure it's really connected with the power of PC.

Please give me some advice. Thanks.

Comment: Your saying its run well in your friends laptop, what is your laptop config ?

Comment: Why not just clean and rebuild the project. I guess its because import issues.

Comment: Okay, some UPD guys. It turnes out, it's just ONE file that causes the trouble. It's pretty big but not the biggest one (and the biggest one works great). I don't know why, but after AS is done parsing this file for warnings etc, it freezes. Also, when there're errors in this file (I tried to make them intentionally) it doesn't freeze. I'm gonna try to locate the problem part of the file...

Answer (score 2):

So, problem solved. I had in my file some if-else-if structure with about 50 conditions. Refactoring it solved the freezing problem. 
That's probably AStudio's way of punishing those who write bad code :)